# Default language layout is showing in TYPO3

Tags: typo3

When I am hiding a layout in German language it gets contents from default language (English). Its not hiding in German language.

[image]

In the above image I have made it hidden. But when I run a page in German language the default english content is loaded for this layout

Typo3 Version : **4.7.4**
Extension is **Grid Element**

Any idea on this?

Comment: Could you please provide more Information about your environment? E.g. what TYPO3 Version and/or extensions you use?

Comment: @KevinDitscheid I have updated my question

Comment: TYPO3 4.7.4, really? it's unsupported since years. Upgrade is important.

Comment: Yes, Its very old website; We planned to upgrade later

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you are describing is intended. When you hide a translation of the page, the default language is shown (*because there is no translation*). To hide the page if no translation exists, there is an option called "Hide page if no translation for current language exists" in the page properties.

If you want this behavior to be true for all your pages, you can also add this to your `localconf.php` in the `typo3conf` folder:

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['FE']['hidePagesIfNotTranslatedByDefault'] = '1';
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer; I will check and let you know; Will this code support for hiding a particular content element in a page. Not a whole page

Comment: I have added this and tried with value 1 or 0; But still default english content is showing

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the settings for `sys_language_mode`. The documentation is for version 8 but it should work for version 4.7, too.

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Config/Index.html#sys-language-mode

Comment: I set this value, but still the default english page element is showing; config.sys_language_mode=content_fallback;0

Comment: Try `strict` instead of `content_fallback`. You check your settings via Template > Root Page > TypoScript Object Browser